# How do i make this function of chars work in java

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, char

Given a character from A to U, print the character and the next 5 characters in the alphabet (space-separated). Print the characters in the same case as the given one.

```
    static void doStuff(char c){
    for(char i='c'; i<='c'+5;i=i+1){
        System.out.print(c+"");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your issue? I see one, easy to fix: replace "" by " " if you want a space.

Comment: Also remove the singlequotes around `c` in for loop and print `i` not `c`.

Comment: I guess you want to remove the quotes around c in the for loop. You might also print i instead of c.

Comment: I did all this, but it does not work.

Comment: @thales78 i = i+1; not work for you because i+1 will result an integer data type value. so you have to typecast externally as i = (char)(i+1);

Answer (score 2):

Error in your code. In for loop remove singlequotes around `c` , use preincrement `i`(`i++`) and print `i` not `c` .Below code work fine.

```
static void doStuff(char c){
   for(char i=c; i<=c+5;i++){
      System.out.print(i+" ");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thx this one worked out just fine! thx thx thx! I wrote i=i++ i guess that was wrong cause just i++ worked. i think i=i+1 should also work? i will try it. Thx a lot again!

Comment: I also tried i=i+1 why doesnt that work. it is the same as i++ isnt it?

Comment: @thales78 i = i+1; not work for you because i+1 will result an integer data type value. so you have to typecast externally as i = (char)(i+1);

Answer (score 1):

```
class Alphabets
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        char ch;

        for( ch = 'a' ; ch <= 'a'+4 ; ch++ )
            System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
public class Alphabets{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        //char c = 'p';
        char c = 'P';

        for(int i = c; i<=c+5; i++){
            System.out.print((char)i +" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Some points at for at you loop -

```
for(char i='c'; i<='c'+5;i=i+1)
```

**1.** char i='c'. Which is incorrect in this context. Now it is referencing the character 'c' whatever the given character to you function is.
I have changed it to `i=c`.

**2.** if you write `i<='c'+5` then there may be an error occurred (based on you jvm version) - **possible loss of precision** while converting the `int` result of the assignment (from right side) to the `i` (at left side).

Comment: These both are the same thing in this context.  Here you can thing `i++` as a short form of `i=i+1`. It worked for me you may try this technique in your method `doStuff(char c)`.

Comment: i=i+1 gives an error with me, so i believe they are not the same.

Comment: Which error dose it gives, please add the error message.

Comment: @Razib,@thales78 i = i+1; not working because i+1 will result an integer data type value. so we have to typecast externally as i = (char)(i+1);  I think this is correct.

Comment: @thales78, @Jarachanthan Ratnakumar. Sorry I have forget to mention that I have made `i` to int instead of `char`. So it works fine without any error if you make `i` to `int` instead of `char`

Comment: @Razib Your think is right.Anyhow we need to typecast to char.In your code you did that in printing statement.

Comment: i kind of understand :-) , really i really understand, kind off. So thank you all for the help and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this -

```
static void doStuff(char c){

        for(int i = c; i<=c+5; i++){
            System.out.print((char)i +" ");
        }
}
```